# Creating Sub-Menu Under a menu by bootstrap while working on ASP.NET MVC -5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created dynamic  navigation bar including sub-menu by using bootstrap in ASP.NET MVC-5 where all item's of menu and sub-menu will come form database.  But I need to make more sub-menu under the existing sub-menu. I am using this code and my desire sub-menu has been created but span is not working. I want to make it just like drop-down style where I can pull down and off  my second sub-menu bar . First spin is working right but second is not working.
How can I do this ??
Thanks is advance.

I am using this code.

```
<div class="user text-center">
    <h4 class="user-name"></h4>
</div>

<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @{
                for (int i = 0; i < menuList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (menuList[i].PARENT_MENU_ITEM_ID.Equals("0"))
                    {
                        <li class="has-submenu">
                            <a href="#"><i class="@menuList[i].MENU_ICON"></i> <span class="nav-label">@menuList[i].MENU_DESCRIPTION</span></a>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                                @for (int j = 0; j < menuList.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    if (menuList[j].PARENT_MENU_ITEM_ID.Equals(menuList[i].MENU_ITEM_ID))
                                    {
                                        <li class="has-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" ><i class="@menuList[i].MENU_ICON"></i> <span class="nav-label">@menuList[j].MENU_DESCRIPTION</span></a>
                                            <ul>
                                                @for (int k = 0; k < menuList.Count; k++)
                                                {

                                                    if (menuList[k].PARENT_MENU_ITEM_ID.Equals(menuList[j].MENU_ITEM_ID) )
                                                    {
                                                        <li >
                                                            <a href="/@menuList[k].MENU_URL">@menuList[k].MENU_DESCRIPTION</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }


                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }

        </ul>
    </nav>

</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use a helper class called rendermenu. I populate a list from d db. it works fine with 2 level menus. my code looks like this:

```
 if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            @foreach (var mp in menuList.Where(p => p.ParentPermission == 0))
            {
                <li id=@mp.PermissionId class="treeview">
                    <a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle">
                        <i class="fa @mp.IconClass fa-fw"></i><span class="text">@mp.PermissionDesc</span>
                        <i class="toggle-icon fa @mp.ToggleIconClass pull-right"></i>
                    </a>

                    @if (menuList.Count(p => p.ParentPermission == mp.PermissionId) > 0)
                {
                @:<ul class="treeview-menu @mp.IsopenClass">
    }

                    @RenderMenuItem(menuList, mp)

                    @if (menuList.Count(p => p.ParentPermission == mp.PermissionId) > 0)
                {
                @:</ul>
                }

                </li>
            }
        </ul>
        @helper RenderMenuItem(List<MenuViewModel> menuList, MenuViewModel mi)
    {
    foreach (var cp in menuList.Where(p => p.ParentPermission == mi.PermissionId))
    {
            @:<li>

                <a href="@Url.Action(@cp.ActionName, @cp.ControllerName)">   <span class="text">@cp.PermissionDesc</span>  </a>
        if (menuList.Count(p => p.ParentPermission == cp.PermissionId) > 0)
        {
        @:<ul class="treeview-menu ">
            }

        @RenderMenuItem(menuList, cp)
        if (menuList.Count(p => p.ParentPermission == cp.PermissionId) > 0)
        {
        @:</ul>
          }
            else
            {
        @:</li>
        }
    }
    }
            }
```

and i have a model similar to :

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public string URL;

    public decimal PermissionId { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string PermissionDesc { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public int ParentPermission { get; set; }
    public string IconClass { get; set; }
    public string IsopenClass { get; set; }
    public string ToggleIconClass { get; set; }

}
```